# QGIS 3.10.0 Interface Problem

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, linux, interface

Everytime I open the software QGIS 3.10.0 A Coruña in Ubuntu 18.04 I get the "default" interface. I can customize/personalize/modify it but it only lasts until I close it.

Edit 1: I have opened it in Windows and it works OK. It must be something of Linux